# How to track week over week growth while accounting for missing weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's pretend we have a `match` table and a pared down version of the table looks something like this:

```
Column                             |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |      Default
-----------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------
uuid                               | uuid                     |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
present_state                      | text                     |           |          |
created_at                         | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
updated_at                         | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
```

I'm trying to get a week over week representation of the number of active matches beginning from some arbitrary date in the past.

Based on the schema, we can know how many new active matches began in a week by looking at the `created_at` column, grouping and counting those. For matches that are finished, we can do something similar by looking at the `updated_at` column and making sure `present_state` is 'finished'.

An additional thing to consider is that there could be weeks where no matches happen at all and matches can go on indefinitely. I have been muddling through trying to coerce some CTEs into providing a table with an entry for each date that a match starts, a table that does the opposite and has a date for when each match ends, and a generated time series that I can join to account for missing weeks. This is what I've got so far:

```
    ; WITH matches_begun AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                date_trunc('day', created_at)::date AS date 
            FROM matches
        )
    , matches_finished AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                 date_trunc('day', updated_at)::date AS date 
            FROM matches 
            WHERE present_state = 'finished'
        )
    , weekly_time_series AS 
        (
            select  generate_series( '2018-01-01', current_date, interval '1 day' )
        )
```

I can't wrap my head around how to return the data that would show how many active matches there are in each week from a point in the past to this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for.

```
with weekly_time_series(report_date) AS (
  select  generate_series( '2018-01-01', current_date, interval '1 day' )
), weekly_counts(report_week, weekly_count) as (
  select date_trunc('week', report_date) 
       , count(distinct uuid) 
    from weekly_time_series
    left join matches
      on date_trunc('day', created_at) <= report_date
     and (present_state <> 'finished' or 
      report_date < date_trunc('day', updated_at))
   group by date_trunc('week', report_date)
)
select report_week
     , weekly_count
     , weekly_count - coalesce(lag(weekly_count) over (order by report_week), 0) delta
  from weekly_counts;
```

Comment: Top notch, provides the exact information. Will read closer to try and understand exactly how it works. Thank you.